# What is the minimum number of observations required for percentile calculation?

Tags: sample-size, descriptive-statistics, quantiles, small-sample

[Here](https://ncss-tech.github.io/soil-range-in-characteristics/why-percentiles.html) it is stated, but not justified, that percentile calculation requires at least three observations.

However, in this [book](https://books.google.it/books?id=BBLRUI4aHhkC&pg=PA106&dq=percentile%20at%20least%203%20observations%20required&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiplI6s0vvdAhWOuIsKHeySAsgQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=percentile%20at%20least%203%20observations%20required&f=false) the authors say that it depends on the percentile value (e.g., for the 25th percentile you need at least 40 observations, i.e. 1/0.025)

Do you have an explanation for that?
Or some other references to look at?

Comment: I think these are all rule of thumbs, you are likely to find many of them.

Comment: You confuse two things that have the same names: in the first instance "percentile" refers to a descriptive statistic of a batch of numbers, whereas in the second it refers to a procedure to estimate a property of a random variable based on a sample.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber . Still, why is 3 the minimum sample size in the first instance?

Comment: It's not.  One could (arguably) compute a percentile with just one observation and it's certainly possible to use "interpolation" (I quote your first link) with two observations.